# ElasticSearch CPU spike every few seconds

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, cpu

I have ElasticSearch node on rather week machine. 
There is only one index with 55K documents plus a number of Marvel indices.

Server experience CPU spike every a few seconds. See below graph. 
I was able to determine that this spikes are coming from ElasticSerach service.

We use ElasticSearch 0.9.13 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

No one is querying node. Only indexing is from Marvel.

Andy ideas what's going on ?

[image: ElasticSearch CPU spikes]